# How to use 2 field names as filter

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, http-redirect

I want to use 2 fields as filter to open a url.
How am I going to code this in javascript.

```
if model=pbga and model=stm
  use matrix2_add.php
otherwise
  use matrix_add.php
```

when this model (e.g. pbga) is chosen under the dropdown list, it will automatically go to this url page `matrix2_add.php`. If a different model is chosen, it will stay on the same page `matrix_add.php`.

These models are in this dropdown list: `>>PBGA >>KRTM >>LST >>MRTO >>HRMS`.

Comment: can you plz add some more details how you want these two urls to be used?

Comment: when this model (e.g. pbga) is chosen under the dropdown list,
it will automatically go to this url page (matrix2_add.php), 
if different model is chosen, it will stay on the same page (matrix_add.php)

models under this dropdown list:
>>PBGA
>>KRTM
>>LST
>>MRTO
>>HRMS

Comment: if(model== 'pbga'){
    window.open("matrix2_add.php");
    else
    window.open("matrix_add.php"); 
    }

Comment: If that works then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(model == 'pbga')
window.open("matrix2_add.php"); // if condition is true
window.open("matrix_add.php"); // else part
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation